# How can I perform a data match between two Kafka topics without any common key?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

> I have a unique issue at hand. I have to match two different sets of
> messages in two separate Kafka topics. Based on the match, I have to
> produce that data to a third topic. Another constraint that I am
> facing is that the Kafka environment I have to work in uses Kafka 2.3.

- config_topic::configId, config
- event_topic::eventId, event
- user_data_topic::customId, alert

> config and event have some matching fields like corpId, secId, fieldId. But, config may or may not have both corpId and secId. At
> least one is mandatory.
>
>       Below is the solution that I have come up with. Please provide your feedbacks and/or better approach.
>
> The only concern with the below approach that I have is data visibility based on different partitions, causing a missing join condition between my KTables and Kstreams.
> Once, I am sure of the approach I will add the logic to filter out
> null config data from the rekeyed tables.
>
> I have simplified the below code by removing things like custom serdes, joined, materialized.

```
//Create KStream on config topic
KStream<Long, Configuration> configStream = builder.stream(CONFIG_TOPIC);
        
//Create KTable with the first key
KTable<Long, List<Configuration>> confTabKeyedWithCaID = configStream.filter((k, v)->v.getCorpId()!=null).
                        groupBy( (k,v) -> v.getCorpId(), Grouped.with() ).
                        aggregate(ArrayList<Configuration>::new, // initializer
                                (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> {
                                    aggValue.add(newValue);
                                    return aggValue;
                                }
                                , Materialized.with());
    
//Create KTable with the second key
KTable<String, List<Configuration>> confTabKeyedWithSecID = configStream.filter((k, v)->v.getCorpId()==null &&
                        v.getSecId()!=null).
                        groupBy( (k,v) -> v.getSecId(), Grouped.with() ).
                        aggregate(ArrayList<AMConfiguration>::new, // initializer
                                (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> {
                                    aggValue.add(newValue);
                                    return aggValue;
                                }
                                , Materialized.with());
    
//Create KStream from second topic
KStream<Long, Event> eventStream = builder.stream(EVENT_TOPIC, Consumed.with()).
                        filter((key, value) -> workflowFilter(value));
    
//Rekey KStream which we got from 2nd topic with first key
KStream<Long, Event>  caEventStrKeyedWithCaID = eventStream.map((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v.getCorpId(), v));
    
//Rekey KStream which we got from 2nd topic with second key
KStream<String, Event>  caEventStrKeyedWithSecID = caEventStream.map((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v.getSecId(), v));
        
//Join Stream and Table keyed with 1st key
KStream<Long, List<Enriched>> enAudListKeyedWithCaID = caAudStrKeyedWithCaID.join(alertConfTabKeyedWithCaID,
                        auditListEnricher, joined1);
        
//Join Stream and Table keyed with 2nd key
KStream<String, List<Enriched>> enEventListKeyedWithSecID = caEventStrKeyedWithSecID.join(confTabKeyedWithSecID,
                        eventListEnricher, joined2);
    
//Perform flatMap operation on 1st keyed Stream
KStream<String, Enriched> eventReKeyed1 = eventListKeyedWithCaID.flatMap((key, recordList)->
                        recordList.stream().map( rec -> KeyValue.pair(""+rec.getEmailId()+rec.getCorpId()+rec.getSecId()+rec.getFieldId(), rec)
                        ).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    
//Perform flatMap operation on 2nd keyed Stream
KStream<String, Enriched> eventReKeyed2 = eventListKeyedWithSecID.flatMap((key, recordList)->
                        recordList.stream().map( rec -> KeyValue.pair(""+rec.getEmailId()+rec.getCorpId()+rec.getSecId()+rec.getFieldId(), rec)
                        ).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    
//Merge both the streams using outer join   
KStream<String, Enriched> enEventReKeyedStream = (eventReKeyed1.outerJoin(eventReKeyed2, enrichedRecMerger, JoinWindows.of(joinWindowSizeMsDuration), joined3));
        
//Rekey the stream for joining with the alert stream
KTable<String, Enriched> eventReKeyedTable = eventReKeyedStream.filter((k,v)-> v!=null && v.getCorpId()!=null).groupBy( (k, v) -> v.getEmailId()+v.getCorpId()+v.getSecId()+v.getFieldId(),
                                Grouped.with() ).aggregate(Enriched::new, // initializer
                                (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> new Enriched(newValue),
                                Materialized.with()).filter((k,v) -> v!=null);
    
//Get a KTable from alert topic
//key: v.getEmailId() + v.getCorpId() + v.getSecId() + v.getFieldId()
KTable<String, Alert> alertKTable = builder.table(ALERT_TOPIC, Consumed.with()).
                        filter((key, value) -> value!=null);
     
//Perform join between enriched and alert data to perform business logic based on update and insert
KTable<String, Alert> eligibleAlertTable = eventReKeyedTable.leftJoin(alertKTable, alertEnricher,
                        Materialized.with()).filter((k,v) -> v!=null);
eligibleAlertTable.toStream().filter((k,v) -> v!=null).to(ALERT_TOPIC, Produced.with());
```